# how to install angularfire in ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, angularfire

i start in development with ionic framework and i can't install angularfire, here is a screenshot .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBmcu.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1XrR.png

Comment: try using `ng add @angular/fire` this should check which version to use based on your angular version

Comment: thanks for the help but it still doesn't work, here are some pictures of the result.

Answer (score 0):

here are the results that the command return

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWqs7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FysdZ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4aId.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llc31.png